Using byte range requests to get frame image from MP4 video
I am trying to make a clone of Youtube and doing it from the tutorial, where the guy is manually creating thumbnail images by using ffmpeg tool to get pictures. That does not sound like an ideal approach to me as if it were a real project, the server would get overloaded real quick as we needed to retrieve it to the server first, generate images and pass it to a bucket then.
I was thinking that I could use Byte Range Requests HTTP approach where I could specify which range I require and then retrieve an image from that part of the video. It's the way  element works in HTML so I figured I could do something similar.
I did some googling and didn't find useful info so ChatGPT tried to assist me here.
Here is my query, but it didn't succeed. I am 100% sure I am doing something wrong as we can't just take blob from the response and magically make an image out of it, but I don't know where to begin.
Here is the code
   const response = await fetch(`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/Video.mp4`, {
    headers: {
      Range: "bytes=0-60824663",
    },
  });

  console.log("response", response.headers.get("Content-Length"));

  const blob = await response.blob();

  const imageUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

  const testImage = document.querySelector(".test-image") as HTMLImageElement;
  testImage.src = imageUrl;

  console.log("imageUrl", imageUrl + ".jpg");


You can use byte range-requests to achieve this for sure, but you also need to understand the MP4 file structure... When you say "Trying to make a clone of Youtube" does that mean you're re-encoding your videos all to the same file settings (format, resolution, etc)? If yes, then maybe you could create a shell MP4 file structure that expects to hold 1 frame. The solution then would be to extract a keyframe from any of your MP4 and paste those bytes into the shell MP4, then send bytes of edited MP4 into the HTML5 player for decoding as a picture.

PS: Have you worked with file bytes before in Javascript? Are you familiar with seeking an Array to look for a specific sequence of elements? Can you work with integers as 8-bit, 16-bit and 32-bit values? I can advise further if you know (or can try handle) these things... Example: To get a keyframe you need to check the section for listing the keyframes within the MP4. Section table is called STSS (SS is a Sync-Sample to MPEG, but it is a video keyframe to us). You want to find an array sequence of [0x73, 0x74, 0x73, 0x73]. Can you find it? What integer value is 0x73747373 anyway?

"does that mean you're re-encoding your videos all to the same file settings". I just wanted to implement preview feature and this was one way to handle this.
It got me interested whether it's feasible to implement such an idea. I am relatively familiar with files structure and know some basic stuff, but apparently it's not enough.    I will look into things you mentioned and would be really grateful if you could assist me further with this!

actually, using ffmpg in a batch job when you upload the video and extracting the frames, then create a single sprite sheet that you load at the beginning and use to create your thumbnails is probably the lowest load on the server - only has to do the extraction once (see https://github.com/sampotts/plyr?tab=readme-ov-file#preview-thumbnails for an example)
